# URLRequest failing on a mac on firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, post

I'm using a class called MultipartURLLoader which just uses URLRequest to POST a
file to a url using the byte data.  It all works fine except in Firefox on a
Mac.  It's fine in other browsers on a Mac and fine on a PC.  I have been
debugging it and can see that the call to MultipartURLLoader works fine if you
don't actually add the file, as soon as I include the "addFile" line it fails.
The code is simply:

```
var ml:MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();
ml.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mp3Saved);
ml.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
ml.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
ml.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
ml.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
ml.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
ml.addFile(sba, new Date().time+'.mp3', 'audio_file');
ml.load(url);
```

The other interesting thing is that none of those events get fired - it doesn't
appear to open, report any progress, report any errors or receive any http
responses.  However after a few minutes the error event is triggered so the
flash is definitely attempting it and timing out.  I downloaded an add-on in
Firefox called Live HTTP Headers so I could watch what was being posted.  And
nothing is at all - the post is just not sent when I try to include the
"addFile" line.

Comment: If `MultipartURLLoader` is a custom class please share the `addFile` function implementation.

Comment: It's a custom class but written by someone else, it's available in google code here: http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/source/browse/trunk/projects/MultipartURLLoader/ru/inspirit/net/MultipartURLLoader.as Thanks!

Comment: Aha, you have to do it over https!  No idea why, it's not documented anywhere